# Docker for Macでimageをpullしたのに/var/lib/dockerディレクトリがない

Tags: macos, docker

Docker for Macを使っています。
imageファイルの格納場所が分からず困っています。

```
docker run hello-world
```

をしました。
もちろん手元にはhell0-worldのimageファイルは無いのでpullされました。

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
```

調べたらimageファイルは/var/lib/dockerに格納されていると色んなサイトに書いてありましたが/var/lib配下にdockerディレクトリが存在しません。
どこにあるのかわかる方教えていただけないでしょうか。

ちなみに

```
docker info
```

をやってみると以下の様に出力されます。

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 3
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge overlay host
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.41-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.4
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.951 GiB
Name: moby
ID: AIWI:PO46:XT4Y:3T4V:DKNZ:AKAH:ALXA:XIIF:NZYO:XD5G:FE6O:S4MT
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 22
 Goroutines: 29
 System Time: 2017-01-19T05:27:23.039809683Z
 EventsListeners: 1
No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

中身に

```
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

と記載があるのですが、このディレクトリにアクセスできません。
と言うかdockerというディレクトリがありません。
わかる方教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

Dockerのimageファイルが直接macOSのファイルシステムには保存されていません。

ユーザのホームディレクトリの下：

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux
```

に`Docker.qcow2`と言う仮想マシン(Linux)のイメージが入っています。

imageファイルはそのマシンのファイルシステムに保存されています。

---

したがって、`/var/lib/docker/aufs`と言うなどは、その仮想マシンの中のパスになっています。